# Stack View Distribution with Dynamic Label Width

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, stackview

I have a `UIStackView` however, the first view of the `subViews` is a `UILabel` and it is not sizing it accordingly.

My code is as per below;

```
private let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let view = UIStackView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.axis = .horizontal
    view.distribution = .fillProportionally
    view.alignment = .trailing
    view.spacing = 8
    return view
}()
```

and I, of course, add my `subViews` within `init` as below;

```
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(currentBidLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(seperator)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(adCreatedAtLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(moreButton)
```

My current result is as per the illustration below;

[image: illustration]

The result I'm looking for is the following;

1. Red = Dynamic Label Width (same as Blue)
2. Green = Fixed Width
3. Blue = Fill Remaining Space
4. Cyan = Fixed Width

Comment: **horizontal** stack view doesn't fit with `.trailing` alignment. Instead you should be using `.fill`/`.top`/`.center`/`.bottom`. Do you need the **AED 400** and **1d ago** both labels occupy the same width?

Comment: When I do fill Proportionally, I get the views smashed up into 0 width...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the desired `ContentHuggingPriority` for each label. The following setup will be matched to your needs

```
redLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(. required, for: .horizontal)
greenLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
blueLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
cyanLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

- `defaultLow` means to fill the rest.
- `required` means fit first.

And other values should be between these two.

Comment: The image provided is an example of my existing result.  I need the red label to be as wide as the text with the blue filling the remainder of space.

Comment: Can you post an image of how you want it to be?

Comment: I have the desired result by red = .required | green = .required | blue = .defaultLow | cyan = .required (please update your answer so I can accept)

Comment: hm. I misunderstood your example. I'm happy you have fixed your issue